How to calculate a determinant for a matrix for x without assinging a value to x
I'm doing simple algebra but want to do it in python as well.
There is a 4X4 matrix where there's x in it. Is there any way to calculate it for x without giving it a value?
import numpy as np

x=float
A = np.array([
            [(x-3), 0, -1, 0],
            [0, (x-3), 0, 0],
            [0, -1, x-3, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, (x-3)]
        ], dtype=np.float_)

np.linalg.det([A])
print (np.linalg.det([A]))

Is my code and the answer should be (x-3)^4
I'm fairly new to python and couldn't find the answer anywhere.

You can use the SymPy library for that:
from sympy import Symbol
from sympy.matrices import Matrix

x = Symbol("x")
A = Matrix([
            [(x-3), 0, -1, 0],
            [0, (x-3), 0, 0],
            [0, -1, (x-3), 0],
            [0, 0, 0, (x-3)]
        ])
print(A.det())

Output:
(x - 3)**4

Here is how you can find the determinant "manually":

Swap the middle two rows (which changes the sign of the determinant)
Swap the middle two columns (which restores the original sign)

...and you get:
     x-3   -1     0     0
      0    x-3   -1     0
      0     0    x-3    0
      0     0     0    x-3

This is a matrix in row echelon form, and so the determinant is the product of the values on the main diagonal, i.e. (x-3)4.

After your edit, the determinant is now (x - 3)**3 * (x - 1). Are you sure you have it right? Where did you get (x - 3)**4 from?

the answer sheet gave me this, so i guess it should be correct?

Just check the explanation in my answer. If you are sure you presented the matrix correctly, then your answer sheet is wrong. But it seems more likely you have a mistake in your matrix. For instance, are you sure about that (x-1). Is it not (x-3)?

i think that might be the explanation

"I think": you are not sure about what the input matrix is? Anyway I updated the answer to reflect the second change to the matrix in your question. I hope this answers your question?
